# Why is Python3 daemon thread instantly closing in console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

this code works in idle3 but in a console(MAC, Windows Linux) thread2 is instantly closing if set to daemon. Is there any explanation for that ? Maybe also a workaround to properly have a daemon thread asking for user input ?

```
import queue
import threading
import sys

def worker(q):
    _text = ''
    while _text == '':
        _text = q.get()
        print('[worker]input was ',_text)
    sys.exit()

def dialog(q):
    while True:
        try:
            _select = input('[dialog]enter text:')
            if _select != '':
            q.put(_select)
        except EOFError:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("bye")
            sys.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)
        if 'esc'.lower() in _select.lower():
            sys.exit()

q = queue.Queue()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=(q,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=dialog,args=(q,))
thread1.setDaemon(True)
thread2.setDaemon(True)
print('start asking')
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

thanks for any hint on the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the child threads die when the main thread exits. The code you've given as example exits directly after starting two child threads. To solve this, you should 'join' the threads back to the main thread. This will make it so the main thread waits for the child threads to die.

```
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

at the end of your file should solve this problem.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Also, why do you want to run this application as daemon?

Comment: " why do you want to run this application as daemon?" is the question, yes.

Comment: thanks that did work. I want to run them as deamon to make sure it they can run independently but be killed if the mainloop dies

Comment: welcome to SO. Nice first answer. My only nitpick would be the question in the end. Yes, it is a mistery why OP wants to do that, but I'd have phrased that differently so it doesn't look too much like a question..